# Area under ROC given the two distributions

Tags: distributions, roc, threshold

I have two distributions p1 and p2 (generating in R using distr package), and I want to compute the area under the ROC curve. To construct the ROC curve, I have to compute the probability of detection $p_D = \int_{T}^{\infty}{p2}$ and the probability of false alarm $p_{FA} = \int_{T}^{\infty}{p1}$ for each threshold T. Thus, for each threshold T, I have a point ($p_{FA}$, $p_{D}$) in the ROC curve. Then, from these points, I can compute the area under the curve. I ask if there is a direct way (function in R or other) to compute the area under the ROC curve using p1 and p2 distributions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look on the [pROC package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf).
You can create a `roc` object with the function `roc`, the AUC is computed by default.